# Azure WebJob, ILogger DI Injected logging to BlobStorage

Tags: azure, logging, dependency-injection, azure-webjobs

I build my services mainly for my API therefore they all get an ILogger<> injected in their contructor. (Azure WebApps)

Now I am using a web job in Azure too and build it with DI following this instruction: https://matt-roberts.me/azure-webjobs-in-net-core-2-with-di-and-configuration/

My problem now is, that I want the service.logger instance to log into the Azure BlobStorage for the web jobs.
Via binding I get an ILogger instance for the time triggered function. But how can I make the service log to the BobStorage?

Thanks in advance.

```
loggerFactory.AddConsole();
loggerFactory.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();

public async Task TimeJob(
    [TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *", RunOnStartup = true)] TimerInfo timerInfo,
    ILogger log
    )
    ....
```

**EDIT**

```
IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection()
.AddLogging(config =>
{
    config.AddConfiguration(configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    config.AddConsole();
    config.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();
 })
 .AddSingleton(configuration)
 ;

 // register services and such
 configurationCallback(services);

 return services.BuildServiceProvider();
```

.

```
        Program.Configuration = SetupHelper.SetupConfiguration(args);
        Program.Services = SetupHelper.SetupServiceProvider(Program.Configuration, Program.ConfigureServices);
        var loggerFactory = Program.Services.GetService<ILoggerFactory>();

        var hostConfig = new JobHostConfiguration(Program.Configuration)
        {
            JobActivator = new CustomJobActivator(Program.Services),
            LoggerFactory = loggerFactory
        };
        hostConfig.Queues.MaxPollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
        hostConfig.Queues.BatchSize = 1;
        hostConfig.UseTimers();

        //hostConfig.Tracing.ConsoleLevel = TraceLevel.Off;

        if (hostConfig.IsDevelopment)
        {
            hostConfig.UseDevelopmentSettings();
        }

        var host = new JobHost(hostConfig);
        host.RunAndBlock();
```

Sample Service

```
public abstract class Service : IService
{
    protected readonly ILogger Logger;
    protected readonly IUserInfo UserInfo;
protected bool Disposed;

protected Service(
    ILogger logger,
    IUserInfo userInfo)
{
    this.Logger = logger;
    this.UserInfo = userInfo;
}

public abstract void Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

I follow the tutorial you provided and download the [demo](https://github.com/mattwoberts/Samples.WebJobs.Core).

You could refer to the following steps to log into blob storage.
Nuget packages:
[image]

TimeJob:

```
public void DoSomethingUseful([TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *", RunOnStartup = true)] TimerInfo timerInfo, ILogger log)
        {
            // Act on the DI-ed class:
            string thing = _usefulRepository.GetFoo();
            Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now} - {thing}");
            ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory()
            .AddConsole()
            .AddDebug()
            .AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();

            log = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<SampleScheduledWebJob>();

            log.LogInformation("hello world");

        }
```

After deployed to azure, I could see the logs under KUDU console and the blob log file as follows:
[image]

[image]

Comment: hi thanks, but the problem is not the ILogger binding in the web job but in the injected services. They should use the ILoggerFactory but they don't. I added some more code.

Comment: @Mario, may be you could refer to this [blog](https://pioneercode.com/post/dependency-injection-logging-and-configuration-in-a-dot-net-core-console-app) about Dependency Injection, Logging and Configuration In A .NET Core Console Application. Then you could [upload core console application as webjob to azure](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/03/07/how-to-deploy-a-net-core-console-application-to-azure-webjob/).

Comment: I follow the above link I provided you, and I could see log info in KUDU. But if you also want to add the log info into blob storage, you could enable `Application Logging(Blob)` in Diagnostics logs.